# How do I extract the path before the "/" in R for multiple list.files?

Tags: r, substring, character, strsplit

Let's say I have the next vector obtained by using *list.files()* in R:

```
paths <- c("/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam/amsterdam1.nc", "/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam/amsterdam2.nc", 
       "/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris/paris1.nc", "/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris/paris2.nc",
       "/home/user/myfolder/CNRM/CLMcom/rcp85/run1/helsinki/helsinki1.nc")

nchar(paths)
[1] 47 47 55 55 63
```

As you can see, the vector path does have different size objects.

I want to obtain a new vector with all the objects from paths but without the file names from inside, something like:

```
> new_paths
[1] "/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam/"                   
"/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam/"                  
[3] "/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris/"       
"/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris/"      
[5] "/home/user/myfolder/CNRM/CLMcom/rcp85/run1/helsinki/"
```

I need this because I want to create a loop where for each *i* in the vector new_paths, I will run a terminal command using *system*

I know there is a possibility with *strsplit* however, I am not expert in manipulating file names in R. Anyone knows a possibility, please?

Comment: Something like `gsub(x = paths,pattern = "/[^/]+$",replacement = "")` ?

Comment: `"[^/]+$"` keeps the last `"/"`, you should post it as an answer if you have time.

Comment: Good point @RLave, answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` to replace pattern in strings. By setting the replacement to an empty string you can effectivly remove a match from a string. So

```
gsub(x = paths, pattern = "[^/]+$", replacement = "")
```

would remove the last part of the path after the last `/`. The regex `"[^/]+$"` matches anything that isn't a `/` until the end of the string. We then replace that match with `""`

Answer (score 5):

For this you can use function `dirname` directly

```
dirname(paths)

#[1] "/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam"                  
#[2] "/home/user/myfolder/ERA/amsterdam"                  
#[3] "/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris"      
#[4] "/home/user/myfolder/CLMcom/HadCruz/run1/paris"      
#[5] "/home/user/myfolder/CNRM/CLMcom/rcp85/run1/helsinki"
```